# Generating Dynamic Table in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to generate a dynamic table in vue where i can manipulate table rows and column value through `<input>` tag.The problem i am facing is my "v-for" loop is not updating according to the assigned variable.

Index.vue

```
<template>
<section>
    <table>
        <tr v-for="row in tableRows">
            <td v-for="col in tableCols">Test</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label>Row</label>
        <input type="number" v-model.lazy="tableRows">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label>Column</label>
        <input type="number" v-model.lazy="tableCols">
    </div>
</section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "index",
    data() {
        return {
            tableRows : 1, 
            tableCols : 1, 
        };
    }
};
</script>
```

The value for the 'tableRows' and 'tableCols' is getting updated according to vue dev tools but the table loop is not generating rows and column accordingly.Can someone help and tell me what am i doing wrong.
Thanks

Comment: You have the data property as `tableCols` & `tableRows` but v-model is bound to `tableCol` and `tableRow`

Comment: @aprouja1 Just a typo sorry,it is assigned to correct variable in my file

Comment: Ah, in that case, the `v-for` is expecting a number. Change `v-model.lazy` to `v-model.lazy.number`

Comment: Got it working, So simple lol. Thank you :)